# Is there any way I can enforce an "API contract" when testing my web app's API and UI separately?

Tags: api, ember.js, continuous-integration, integration-testing, apache-phoenix

I'm developing an Ember.js app with a Phoenix API. I have followed someone's advice to keep the UI and API as separate projects, and I know that I can use ember-cli-mirage to mock my API during development and testing. But this makes me really nervous. I'm used to having a suite of integration tests that tests the UI and API together. I know for a fact that one day me or another developer is going to make a breaking change in one of the projects, and we won't realise it until users start complaining.

On the other hand, I really like the idea of mocking the API in the client where Ember.js is running. It should make development and testing really fast.

Is there a way that I can extract a high-level description of my API end points, and use that as a sanity check to make sure that my mocked API fulfills all of the requirements? For example, if I add or remove a route in my API server, I want my Ember.js tests to fail immediately if the mocked API doesn't match those changes. Because I know that this is going to happen one day. It's especially concerning if I want to use continuous deployment after successful builds.

Or should I just start up a real API server on the CI machine, and run my tests against that?

I kind of like the idea of enforcing an API contract, though. I could also reuse the principle in any future mobile or desktop apps. You get some guarantee of consistency without having to install a ton of dependencies and spin up a real API.

Another idea: Maybe I write a set of API acceptance tests, but run them against both the real and the mocked API. And then I could include the mocked API code (ember-cli-mirage) inside my main API repo, and link it into the Ember.js repo as a submodule.

How are people currently approaching this issue?

Comment: we have the same question. And finally we decide to keep only unit tests inside ember-test ( and move all logic with store into services, it's make unit testing much more easy and allow skip mirage ) and add integration tests with selenium ( nightwatch.js or something else ).  From our proposal there where create cronjob which will ask real api and save responses into mirage fixtures, but it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ember tests should focus on the behavior of the client application itself, not the implementation details of your API. While it is more trouble to maintain a separate mocked instance of your API logic in ember-cli-mirage, in reality you should only be adding Mirage endpoints and behavior as your Ember tests require it.

If you add a route to your API server, and no Ember code interacts with it, there should be no need to write an Ember test that consumes a mocked Mirage endpoint.

If you remove a route or change behavior in your API, it makes sense that you would want any affected Ember tests to immediately fail, but rewriting those Ember tests and Mirage endpoints to mirror the new behavior is just the cost of doing business.

It's more work in the long run, but I think your tests will be more meaningful if you treat the API and your mocked endpoints in Mirage as separate concerns. Your Ember tests shouldn't test whether your server works - they should only verify that your Ember code works given known constraints.

Perhaps one way to avoid omissions in your test suites is to enforce a (human) policy wherein any change to the API's behavior is specced out in a formal testing DSL like [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin), at least to document the requirements, and then use that as the single reference for writing the new tests and code that will implement the changes.